# Jasmine array comparison

Tags: jasmine

I don't understand this output:

```
Expected [ ({ label: 'label1', value: 'value1' }), ({ label: 'label2', value: 'value2' }), ({ label: 'label3', value: 'value3' }) ] to equal [ Object({ label: 'label1', value: 'value1' }), Object({ label: 'label2', value: 'value2' }), Object({ label: 'label3', value: 'value3' }) ]
```

Jasmine tells me that the test is failing and that this is the problem. I don't see the problem. I see two arrays of objects which *should* be equal to each other and *do* equal each other.

Is there some subtlety I'm not getting? Is it to do with the expectation not actually being identified as 'Object({ ... })'? Did something change with jasmine while I was away from my Mac not running npm install at all? Did somebody change the gravitational constant of the universe?

Answers on a postcard. Or here would be better.

Comment: Can you show the code of your test?

Answer (score 1):

What is your test assertion? If using `.toEqual` it should work - although the objects are different, `.toEqual` performs a deep comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Jasmine is doing a comparison at the object level, not at the properties-on-object level.

IIRC Jasmine doesn't have a deep-equal (where, iirc, Mocha does), however, you can do:

```
result.forEach(function(item) {
  var item = expectedResults.filter(function(e) {
    return e.label === item.label && e.value === item.value;
  })
  expect(item).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: You could also write a matcher for Jasmine to do a deep-equal comparison. It will make your tests a lot clearer and it's probably the right thing to do.

Comment: Jasmine toEqual uses underscores toEqual, which is a deep comparison. https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L2833